# Fragment banner ad does not shows ads

Tags: android, xml, android-fragments

I Recently was successful in making the banner ads work.
Now I tried to transfer in a fragment the banner ad, and even if everything seems to work: the banner ad doesn't show anything.

Here the `MainActivity`:

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Toolbar myToolbar = (Toolbar) findViewById(R.id.calculator_toobar);
        setSupportActionBar(myToolbar);

        // Check that the activity is using the layout version with
        // the fragment_container FrameLayout
        if (findViewById(R.id.ads_banner) != null) {

            // However, if we're being restored from a previous state,
            // then we don't need to do anything and should return or else
            // we could end up with overlapping fragments.
            if (savedInstanceState != null) {
                return;
            }

            // Create a new Fragment to be placed in the activity layout
            BannerAdsFragment firstFragment = new BannerAdsFragment();

            // In case this activity was started with special instructions from an
            // Intent, pass the Intent's extras to the fragment as arguments
            firstFragment.setArguments(getIntent().getExtras());

            // Add the fragment to the 'fragment_container' FrameLayout
            getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction().add(R.id.ads_banner, firstFragment).commit();

        }
    }
```

Here the `main_activity.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/activity_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    tools:context="postfixcalculator.mattiarubini.com.postfixcalculator.MainActivity">         

    <FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/ads_banner"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="50dp" />


    <!--ActionBar-->
    <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/calculator_toobar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#f45342"
        android:elevation="4dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textEquation"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="26sp"
        android:padding="10sp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:text="Equation" />

</LinearLayout>
```

the `BannerAdsFragment`:

```
public class BannerAdsFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "MainActivity";
    private AdView mAdView;

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.banner_ad_on_top, null);
        mAdView = (AdView) rootView.findViewById(R.id.adView);
        AdRequest adRequest = new AdRequest.Builder().build();
        mAdView.loadAd(adRequest);
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        return inflater.inflate(R.layout.banner_ad_on_top, container, false);
    }
}
```

The `banner_ads_on_top.xml`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

        <!--Banner ad-->
        <RelativeLayout xmlns:ads="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
            android:layout_height="50dp"
            android:layout_width="match_parent">
            <com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView
                android:id="@+id/adView"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
                ads:adSize="BANNER"
                ads:adUnitId="@string/banner_ad_unit_id">
            </com.google.android.gms.ads.AdView>
        </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are inflating the layout again which destroys the previous view.

instead of:

```
 return inflater.inflate(R.layout.banner_ad_on_top, container, false);
```

use:

```
return rootView;
```